# how to keep control of my root view while loading a view controller as a subview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a root view which contains a table and a button. When I press the button a view is loaded on top of the root view but keeps my root view visible. The view that appears after the button is pressed is suppose to act as a menu that is scrollable. My problem is that when I want to close the menu that appears.

Im using the `[self.view removeFromSuperview]` on the subview that appears on top of my root view. When the subview disappears I'm not able to make selections from my table.

How can I get rid of my subview and still keep control of my root view. Also how can I change what my root view displays based on the menu selection I have made. Since my menu is a subview of my root view.

I'm not sure if these things are possible. I have been experimenting but so far I lose control of my root view. I'm able to scroll up and down my table and relaunch the menu subview. But I cannot make any selections from the table. Also I'm unable to change what my root view displays after I have made a choice from the menu.

Please if anyone could shed some light on this issue for me I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Whats the code you are using to display the view in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I don't fully understand what you are doing, so if my answer is rubbish, please forgive my.
As far as I understand, you have a ViewController with another ViewController as a subview. If so, you might very well run into unexpected behavior, since, according to the documentation

> Each custom view controller object you create is responsible for managing exactly one screen’s worth of content.

There are some exceptions (e.g. a ViewController inside a TabBarController) but a ViewController inside a ViewController is definitely not the way to go.

So, if you want to show a ViewController after your Button is pressed, show it as a [Modal ViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW1) by using the "presentModalViewController:animated:" method of your "superview". You can make your selection in the ModalView and dismiss it via "dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:"